# Solving $3^n \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{(n/2)!}(1+e^{-\pi}) 2^{-\frac{3n}{2}} \le 2^{-n/2+8}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is it possible to solve the following inequality explicitly? Or at least proving it with some method?
$$3^n \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{(n/2)!}(1+e^{-\pi}) 2^{-\frac{3n}{2}} \le 2^{-n/2+8}$$
For $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am reading a research paper where they leave this up to the reader and I couldn't find a way to separate the variables, or even with Stirling's approximation. Also taking the derivative of the function results in a mess.

Graphing the functions makes the inequality seem plausible (the dots are $f(a)$, and the dashes are $f(b))$:

[image]

Comment: How about showing that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$

Comment: This has to be true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm not exactly sure how the end behavior would impact the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to: $$\dfrac{\pi^{n/2}}{(n/2)!}(1+e^{-\pi})\leq 256\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$ 
or $$f(n) = \dfrac{(2.25\cdot\pi)^{n/2}}{(n/2)!}\leq\dfrac{256}{1+e^{-\pi}}=245.395...$$

Now, you can simply observe that the LHS is eventually decreasing eventually because a factorial is increasing more rapidly than an exponent. This means there is a single, global maximum at some $n = k$, where it has to satisfy the inequalities: $$f(k-1)<f(k)$$ and $$f(k)>f(k+1).$$

If you solve these inequalities, then you can easily find that $k = 14$, which gives the maximum of $f(k) = 174.943.$